# Mongo query operation for matching two elements within same index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Scope of Project**: I am making a newsfeed, like Facebook. And I have a like button feature that will add a like to a post item when clicked.

**Problem** Lets say I have two posts, post A and post B.

If I like post A and like again then my server returns "User already liked post", okay that works.

However, if I like post B then the server returns the same "User already liked post"

**Query:**

```
Feed.findOne({
      owner: req.body.authorId,
      $and: [
        {
          "posts.likes.likeList": {
            $elemMatch: { user: req.user._id }
          }
        },
        { posts: { $elemMatch: { _id: req.body.postId } } }
      ]
    }).then(checkedFeed => {
      if (checkedFeed) {
        return res.status(400).json({ Error: "User has already liked post" });
      }
```

**What I think the problem is** When the user likes post B while post A is liked, the `$and` operator matches the `req.user._id` with the `posts.likes.likeList` of post A in the first index of the `$and` array. Then, it matches the `_id` of `posts` in the second  index of the `$and` array. And then returns the entire feed as a match.

So, if I am correct in this regards, how do I write a query that matches the post id (the second index of the `$and` array) with the `post.likes.likeList` list of users?

**Schema**

```
{
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "userType"
  },
  posts: [
    {
      likes: {
        totalLikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        likeList: [
          {
            user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
            avatar: { type: String },
            name: { type: String },
            date: {
              type: Date,
              default: Date.now
            }
          }
        ]
      }
});
```

**Test Data***

```
    {

//POST B <-------
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a61bc5b835b2428289c1b"),
        "owner" : ObjectId("5c9bf6eb1da18b038ca660b8"),
        "posts" : [ 
            {
                "likes" : {
                    "totalLikes" : 0,
                    "likeList" : []
                },
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a61bc5b835b2428289c1c"),
                "postBody" : "Test text only",
                "author" : {
                    "userType" : "User",
                    "user" : ObjectId("5c9bf6eb1da18b038ca660b8"),
                    "name" : "Amari DeFrance",
                    "avatar" : "https://stemuli.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-e1367a7a-41c2-4ab4-9cb5-621d2008260f.jpg"
                }
            }, 
            {
//Post A <------
                "likes" : {
                    "totalLikes" : 1,
                    "likeList" : [ 
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5d0a66efbac13b4ff8b3b1c8"),
                            "user" : ObjectId("5c9bf6eb1da18b038ca660b8"),
                            "avatar" : "https://stemuli.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-e1367a7a-41c2-4ab4-9cb5-621d2008260f.jpg",
                            "name" : "Amari DeFrance",
                            "date" : ISODate("2019-06-19T16:46:39.177Z")
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "postBody" : "Test photo",
                "author" : {
                    "userType" : "User",
                    "user" : ObjectId("5c9bf6eb1da18b038ca660b8"),
                    "name" : "Amari DeFrance",
                    "avatar" : "https://stemuli.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-e1367a7a-41c2-4ab4-9cb5-621d2008260f.jpg"
                },
                "date" : ISODate("2019-06-19T16:25:26.123Z")
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 3
    }
```

**New Query per suggested answer**

```
  Feed.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: ["$owner", req.body.authorId]
              },
              {
                $anyElementTrue: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$posts",
                    in: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $eq: ["$$this._id", req.body.postId]
                        },
                        {
                          $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                              input: "$$this.likes.likeList",
                              as: "like",
                              in: {
                                $eq: ["$$like.user", req.user._id]
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]).then(checkedFeed => {
      if (checkedFeed.length !== 0) {
        return res.status(400).json({ Error: "User has already liked post" });
      }
```

[MongoDB query test with post B having liked post from the user](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_UODjHiIiiH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to transform `likeList` into an array of boolean values. Then you can use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) to check if any like belongs to particular user. Then you need to do the same trick for `posts` (outer array), combining both conditions with `$and` will bring you desired results, try:

```
Feed.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $eq: [ "$owner", req.body.authorId ] },
                    {
                        $anyElementTrue: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$posts",
                                in: {
                                    $and: [
                                        { $eq: [ "$$this._id", req.body.postId ] },
                                        {
                                            $anyElementTrue: {
                                                $map: {
                                                    input: "$$this.likes.likeList",
                                                    as: "like",
                                                    in: { $eq: [ "$$like.user", req.user._id ] }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dej5H2fIhg7)

Comment: I am testing this and it is returning the same response. I am going to look over the documentation for some of these mongodb aggregation operators for a moment. I've never really used them. Thank you so much, you've put me down the right path I feel like.

Comment: @user10204157 could you please compare https://mongoplayground.net/p/uL7haNSdfc8 (your query) with https://mongoplayground.net/p/dej5H2fIhg7 (my solution) ?

Comment: When I was querying the Db I didnt check if my promise was an empty array. That was the issue. However, now that I am able to like a separate post (post B), it's allowing me to like again. (I updated my question)

Comment: @user10204157 does it mean that the answer was helpful or the problem is not solved yet ?

Comment: It was helpful. I may end up having to create another question to address the issue with the query allowing the user to like the post again even after being in the `like.likeList` already.

Comment: @user10204157 awesome, please link it here, I will try to take a look later

Comment: I unmarked it as answered because I continued to test it. But the query is always returning no document even if there is an element that does exist.

Comment: @user10204157 here's an example where this query returns the document since postId and userId belong to the same post: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Md6BqGGE3Ex

Comment: Thanks im not sure why I kept getting no documents even after adding the value itself. I wrote my own mapping function after getting the needed feed. You've given me a lot of insight to how to use aggregate, thanks again!